# Why are some elements lower than others in my layout?

Tags: html, css

While writing HTML, the div elements on my page started being positioned with random margin amounts after reloading the page.

As you can see, the second div is clearly below the 1st and 2nd divs while the 3rd div is for some reason above the 1st div. All of these elements have the same margin.

[image]

```css
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1vh;
width: 30vw;
height: 30vh;
margin: 2vh;
padding: 1vh;
border-radius: 2vh;
display: inline-block;
background: #e3e3e3;
border-color: #3eabfe;
font-family: "Quicksand",
sans-serif;
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

```html
<div class="post">
  <div class="post-title"> {{ post['display'] }} <a class="link" href="https://twitter.com/{{ post['username'] }}" target="_blank"> @{{ post['username'] }} </a> </div>
  <div class="post-description"> {{ post['text'] }} </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which class is all that CSS assigned to?

Comment: As Millhorn said, your CSS is not valid

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise the demo above so it shows your problem.

Comment: it's the post class

Comment: @isherwood I don't see how the post doesn't show the problem.

Comment: Click the _Run code snippet_ button.

Answer (score 0):

Put your cards in a container div to set them like cards and then Try this to style the cards:

```
.container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(17em, 1fr))
}
.post{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: .3em;
  margin: .5em;
 padding: .5em;
 border-radius: 1em;
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 gap: 1em;

 background: #e3e3e3;
 border-color: #3eabfe;

 font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you changed?

Comment: Step 1: I created a div with class name "container"
Step 2: I placed all the .post divs inside the .container div
step 3: I created a Grid layout on the .container div for all the .post divs to display them like cards
Step 4: I made all the I organised all the content inside the .post div

The .container div uses grid to make the posts all equal size and puts them on equal positions. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you explain what you changed _in your answer_? Again, see [answer].

Comment: I added code snippet for the .container class and changed all the units from vw/vh to em. I also changed the display property for the .post class to flex and set it to column wrap.